# Invalid object name 'Table_2'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to replace two charachter in sql, when use this script in multi schema database 
I received this error :

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid object name
>   'PayPersonAccounts'. Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid object
>   name 'PayPersonAccounts'. Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid
>   object name 'CMRDirectDeliveryPartHeader'

```
USE Test
DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(MAX),@Column NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR
FOR

SELECT T.name, /* Table */
       C.name  /* Column */
FROM sysobjects T,syscolumns C
WHERE  T.id = C.id  AND T.xtype = 'u' /* User Table */
                    AND (C.xtype = 99 /* ntext */
                    OR C.xtype = 35   /* text */
                    OR C.xtype = 231  /* nvarchar */
                    OR C.xtype = 167  /* varchar */
                    OR C.xtype = 175  /* char */
                    OR C.xtype = 239  /* nchar */)

OPEN Table_Cursor FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @Table,@Column
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    EXEC ('Update [' + @Table + '] Set [' + @Column + '] = REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST([' + @Column +  '] as nvarchar(max)), NCHAR(1610), NCHAR(1740)), NCHAR(1603), NCHAR(1705))')
FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @Table,@Column
END CLOSE Table_Cursor 
DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor
```

Comment: Can you check the schema name? Probably schema might be different..

Comment: It is always best to use schemaname.tablename

Comment: Small remarks: What will you do with computed columns? They are also selected here. And if you can, use `QUOTENAME` and `CONCAT`. Just looks a lot neater.

Comment: Thanks for your help
How to resolve this problem, and which part of this script must change ?

Comment: Aside: Say "hello" to my little friend [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). Do the table and column names come from an absolutely trustworthy source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your schemaname is missing.. Trying checking this changed query

```
USE Test
DECLARE @SchemaName SYSNAME, @Table NVARCHAR(MAX),@Column NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR
FOR

SELECT s.Name  --schemaname
    , T.name, /* Table */
      C.name  /* Column */
FROM sysobjects T inner join 
syscolumns C on
T.id = C.Id
inner join sys.schemas s
on T.uid = s.schema_id
where T.xtype = 'u' /* User Table */
                    AND (C.xtype = 99 /* ntext */
                    OR C.xtype = 35   /* text */
                    OR C.xtype = 231  /* nvarchar */
                    OR C.xtype = 167  /* varchar */
                    OR C.xtype = 175  /* char */
                    OR C.xtype = 239  /* nchar */)

OPEN Table_Cursor FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @SchemaName, @Table, @Column
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    EXEC ('Update [' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @Table + '] Set [' + @Column + '] = REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST([' + @Column +  '] as nvarchar(max)), NCHAR(1610), NCHAR(1740)), NCHAR(1603), NCHAR(1705))')
FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @SchemaName, @Table,@Column
END CLOSE Table_Cursor 
DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor
```

Comment: As Matias suggested you can use sys.tables or Information_Schema.tables where you will have table_schema readily available

Comment: Not tested the code - try printing the code and check whether it generates your required update scripts

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'Pay.PayPersonAccounts'.
Msg 16924, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns

Comment: Yes I think it is problem due to QuoteName. I modified now. Can you check?

Comment: Thanks again 

Msg 16924, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns.

Comment: FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @Table,@Column

Comment: Yep.. FETCH NEXT need to add with @SchemaName

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the complete table name with the schema. And just to be sure enclose tabe names. Also use sys.tables for tables:
sys.tables

QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(T.name)